# Slow in compilation of Chess games

Tags: fonts, compiling, chess, chessboard

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt,top=1.5cm,nofoot,bottom=0cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%% FONT
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font

%% OWN command

\newcommand{\game}[3]{
    \item \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
    (#1 points) \\
    \chessboard[
    setfen= #3,
    mover= #2
    ]
    \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}\raggedbottom
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{enumerate}[Q1.]


\lhead{Elementary Mates}
%% 01 - 06
\game{1}{w}{1k/pb3p/3p3r/3p3p/1R2rP/2R4B/PP4P/6K}
\game{1}{w}{5b/1pp/6pp/1P1k1p/2KPp/4P/rn2Nppp/2R3K}
\game{1}{b}{/1p2rk/p1pK1n/P/1P/7Q}
\game{1}{b}{4k/p4p//R2pPKPp/3P3P/7r}
\game{1}{w}{r2qkbnr/1p3ppp/p1n/2P/2bpN//PPP1QPPP/R1B1K1NR}
\game{1}{b}{/1p3k/4p1p/Pp2P/1b2qp/1K2Q1p/3B}
%% 07 - 12
\game{1}{b}{2r1r/6k/3pp1p/2n/1p3P//1PP/1NKQ}
\game{1}{w}{4B//3BK/r4pk//6PP}
\game{1}{w}{2r/p4p/4b2p/2p2p1P/2P1k1p/1PKN/P5P/3R}
\game{1}{w}{r1b4R/1p2pkb/p4p2/6pp/B/2N2q1P/PP3PP/4R1K}
\game{1}{w}{/r5p/4bp1p/1R2p1kP/4P1P/5PK}
\game{1}{w}{/5p1p//2B3b/5kP/1P1K1p1P}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Obviously I have nearly 300 pages in my file. So each of these `[xxxx]` takes about half a second to compile. I don't know why it is so slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code isn't so good. It uses a lot of \ifthenelse switches and similar which are quite slow. I can only say to my defense that at the time I wrote it neither expl3 nor l3benchmark was available. So until I find the time to rewrite the package you will have to live with the slow processing. Just to show the difference in both approaches, here some benchmarking (the first time is the old code, the second the one with the new code):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,ifthen}
\usepackage{l3benchmark}
\newcommand\test{empty}
\newcommand\testref{empty}
\newcounter{ufcnt}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark:n{
\ifthenelse%
     {\equal{\test}{empty}}%
     {\stepcounter{ufcnt}}%
     {}}

\fp_use:N\g_benchmark_time_fp

\int_new:N\g_uf_tmpa_int
\benchmark:n{
\tl_if_eq:NNTF
     \test\testref%
     {\int_gincr:N\g_uf_tmpa_int}%
     {}}

\par
\fp_use:N\g_benchmark_time_fp

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought it was a system bug or something. That’s fine then. I can live with it for now.